# Inquiry regarding Whitelabeling and app-Linking Issue in iOS Application

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, applinks

I am currently in the process of whitelabeling my iOS application and have encountered a specific issue that when I generate unsigned binaries and subsequently sign them separately, I face difficulties in making app-links and push notifications function properly. To provide some context, I are utilizing the same signing key, app name, and other metadata as my regular app during the testing phase.

Interestingly, the application works seamlessly when built and signed in a single step, using identical code and metadata details. However, the issue arises when I opt for the generation of an unsigned binary followed by a separate signing step.
I are using flutter framework for development.

Any insights or suggestions you could share would be immensely valuable and appreciated.

Comment: Universal links and push notifications are both linked to the team identifier. Are you certain that you are signing with the correct team identifier?

Comment: Thanks for the respose.
Yes, team identifier is same as regular builds and is not changed for this test build.